# Button method suddenly stopped working

Tags: java, android, eclipse, methods

So I have a spinner, a button and edittext, and according to which item is selected on spinner and which value is in edittext something happens on button click. It used to work perfectly and now it suddenly crashes every time I click the button. I have no idea what I have done to ruin it so I am kindly asking you for some help. I've been stuck like this for hours and I just can't point a finger to what ruined the code.

Button click method (As you can see in case 1, I added shared preferences to a comment just to make sure this isn't what's runing the code):

```
public void submitQuantityButton (View v){
    Button submitButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.submitButton);
    final Spinner sItems = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
    final Context context = this;
    final CheckBox cb4 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox4);

    submitButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            final int position = sItems.getSelectedItemPosition();
            EditText quantityEditText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);

            switch (position){
            case 0:
                AlertDialog.Builder spinnerErrorBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
                spinnerErrorBuilder.setTitle("Warning");
                spinnerErrorBuilder.setMessage("Please choose an item from the list");
                spinnerErrorBuilder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                        dialog.cancel();
                    }
                });
                AlertDialog spinnerError = spinnerErrorBuilder.create();
                spinnerError.show();
                break;
            case 1:
                String items = quantityEditText.getText().toString();
                cb4.setText("Elaborate Totem (" + items + "/250)");
                //saveItemQuantity("cb4", cb4.getText().toString());
                break;
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Button XML:

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/submitButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/checkBox25"
    android:text="@string/addMaterial"
    android:onClick="submitQuantityButton" />
```

Logcat file:

```
06-23 15:05:29.276: E/AndroidRuntime(22681): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-23 15:05:29.276: E/AndroidRuntime(22681): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
06-23 15:05:29.276: E/AndroidRuntime(22681):    at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3599)
06-23 15:05:29.276: E/AndroidRuntime(22681):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4204)
06-23 15:05:29.276: E/AndroidRuntime(22681):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17355)
06-23 15:05:29.276: E/AndroidRuntime(22681):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
06-23 15:05:29.276: E/AndroidRuntime(22681):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
06-23 15:05:29.276: E/AndroidRuntime(22681):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
06-23 15:05:29.276: E/AndroidRuntime(22681):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
06-23 15:05:29.276: E/AndroidRuntime(22681):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-23 15:05:29.276: E/AndroidRuntime(22681):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
06-23 15:05:29.276: E/AndroidRuntime(22681):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
06-23 15:05:29.276: E/AndroidRuntime(22681):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
06-23 15:05:29.276: E/AndroidRuntime(22681):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-23 15:05:29.276: E/AndroidRuntime(22681): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
06-23 15:05:29.276: E/AndroidRuntime(22681):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-23 15:05:29.276: E/AndroidRuntime(22681):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
06-23 15:05:29.276: E/AndroidRuntime(22681):    at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3594)
06-23 15:05:29.276: E/AndroidRuntime(22681):    ... 11 more
06-23 15:05:29.276: E/AndroidRuntime(22681): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.Spinner cannot be cast to android.widget.Button
06-23 15:05:29.276: E/AndroidRuntime(22681):    at com.example.gw2legendary.Bifrost.submitQuantityButton(Bifrost.java:967)
06-23 15:05:29.276: E/AndroidRuntime(22681):    ... 14 more
```

Comment: have you tried to clean and rebuild?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what was the problem, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These kinds of errors normally happen when you have moved two elements inside your layout (switched their places). A Project --> Clean in Eclipse normally resolves this, which makes Android rebuild the R-class.

Comment: Yes! It works! Thank you so much, I can't believe I was stuck with this for hours and the solution was so simple